# echo to /etc/sudoers causing pasrse error

Tags: 12.04, python, sudo

Using [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/en/latest/) if I echo to sudoers file for second time the file got corrupted works fine for first echo. What could be the reason?

First echo:

```
sudo('echo "django    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers')
```

Second echo:

```
sudo('echo "celery    ALL(www-data) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/unoconv" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers')
```

After second echo command and when trying to do sudo I am getting parse error and I am not able to recover the sudoers file again, I have to create a new instance unfortunately:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 28 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 28
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

There is no syntax issue as such in second command because if I type it manually using `visudo` it works fine. And I don't think that its fabric related issue. Fabric is just executing commands on the remote server.

Comment: as posted, the line in your second echo is wrong; I tried manually adding `django    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
celery    ALL(www-data) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/unoconv` to my sudoers using visudo and I also get a syntax error. I think you need `=` before `(www-data)`, but in any case there *is* an error there. If as you say typing it manually works, I'm pretty sure what you're typing is different.

Comment: @roadmr can you point out whats wrong in the second echo command? I guess it might be I am using 4 spaces instead of a tab in between `django` and `ALL` ??

Comment: A tip to validate sudo syntax without destroying your sudoers file: `echo 'blah blah' | visudo -f - -c`. This will at least tell you if the line looks OK or has errors, without touching your sudoers file.

Comment: Oops sorry. I missed the `=` sign. But as you are saying it is still throwing error then what would be the reason? Do you see any other issue? I see in my sudoers file I have `=` sign `ALL=(www-data)`so its a good catch from your side but everything else is same.

Comment: it's not the spaces, I'm pretty sure it's the lack of =. Give it a try :)

Comment: Aamir, I suggest you try the `visudo -f -` trick on each line you're trying to add to your sudoers file, at least if you narrow it down to a single line it will be easier.

Comment: Is this right? `echo "celery    ALL(www-data) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/unoconv" | visudo -f - -c` ?? I intentionally missed the `=` sign here just for testing if it throws error.

Comment: AAmir yes, that's correct.

Comment: @roadmr you are right missing `=` was the issue. Please post as an answer. I was so stupid to missed that (facepalm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted, the line in your second echo is wrong; I tried manually adding

```
django ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL 
celery ALL(www-data) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/unoconv
```

to my sudoers using visudo and I also get a syntax error. You need = before (www-data) in the second line.

A tip to validate sudo syntax without destroying your sudoers file: `echo 'blah blah' | visudo -f - -c`. This will at least tell you if the line looks OK or has errors, without touching your sudoers file.